# IOS: strange crash for an imageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

In my app I have a tableView with custom cell, this is .h of custom cell

```
    @interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

    IBOutlet UILabel *prod;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *back;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *prod;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *back;
```

and it's .m

```
@implementation TableViewCell

@synthesize prod, back;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [prod release];
    [back release];
}


@end
```

in my delegate methods of tableView I have this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle...
```

but when I delete last row of my tableView I have an EXC_BAD ACCESS here:

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [prod release];
    [back release]; <-- for this I have a EXC BAD ACCESS
}
```

why?

Comment: If `prod` and `back` are created from a xib (Interface Builder), they can be weak references I think (already retained by parent view, i.e. main view). Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: Did you try enabling zombies? When are `prod` and `back` set, and to what values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `dealloc` method.

Additionally, as you've properties, make use of them. Instead of releasing directly assign `nil` to them:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.prod = nil;
    self.back = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```